# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Out of Office reply with Dear <senders name>?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation

Is there a way to set an Out of Office Auto reply that includes the name of the sender?

My company has a large directory, and I think it would be awesome to include:

Dear ,

example:
John.Smith@work.com sends me an email. My auto-reply says:

Dear John,

etc etc.

Comment: This will be hard to determine the name unless it's an internal email as if an email comes from 'genericaddress@microsoft.com' it would put the 'genericaddresss' as the name. Is it ok to have the email address rather than a name?

Comment: I would prefer to have the name. Say my email is John.Smith@work.com. Most all of the replies will be in the same format, such as Bill.Jones@work.com, or Betty.Lue@work.com. If the only way is to get the email address instead of the name, that's the best I can do I suppose!